# Replacing words inside file

Tags: c++, c, linux, ubuntu

I have a very large code in which I have by mistake I have used `unsigned` instead of `uint64_t`. Due to this blunder my code does not work for large values greater than 4 byte. Now I want to recify this mistake...but it impossible for me to go into each file (there are 540 files) and replace `unsigned` with `uint64_t`. Is there some linux command or some automated method which may do it for me.

I just want to replace word *`unsigned`* by *`uint64_t`*. I dont want words like *`unsignedFunction`* to get replaced by *`uint64_t`*.

**EDIT:**
When I replace it for functions of the following form:

```
   static inline unsigned readUint32Aligned(const unsigned char* data) { return toHost(*reinterpret_cast<const unsigned*>(data)); }
```

The converted function being :

```
   static inline uint64_t readUint32Aligned(const uint64_t char* data) { return toHost(*reinterpret_cast<const uint32_t*>(data)); }
```

It gives me the error:

> error: ‘data’ was not declared in this scope

Is there something other than `uint64_t` which I can do for replacing, which may work for functions of the above form?

Sorry there isn't its probably a typo.

Comment: Use an editor, with find in files utility. Search & Replace. Problem Solved  !

Comment: Is this question really programming-related? You are asking for a text-replacing problem/tool, not for a C/C++ programming problem.

Comment: @Manu343726 Yes it is programming related as replacing unsigned by uint64_t though does handle large values, yet it throws a lot of errors

Comment: @Manu343726 What I really want to do is increase the range of my values from unsigned(4bytes) to 8bytes. I thought uint64_t would work. But it does not. As explained in my edit

Comment: `unsigned`is a specifier, not a data type. When you write `unsigned` only, its only a shortcut for `unsigned int`. Sentences like `unsigned uint64_t char` have no sense at all. Thats why the compiler shows you errors.

Comment: @Manu343726 Thanks for replying. Then what should I use instead of unsigned. Such that I dont have to go to each and every file for checking and replacing unsigned. And which works for unsigned uint64_t char.

Comment: Your problem is: Text-replacing tools cannot differentiate when `usnigned` is used as a specifier, or as a shortcut for `unsigned int`. So replacing `unsigned`with `uint64_t` results in errors like in your replacing example. You should go to search a good C++ refactorizer, which can parse (Almost parcially) C++ code and execute semantic replacing, not token-replacing only.

Comment: Why is there still a string `unsigned` in your "replaced" version? Usually, "replacing" something implies the original is gone.

Comment: @Jongware [Exactly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19728113/replacing-words-inside-file#comment29311187_19728171)

Answer (score 2):

Use `sed` and the pattern `s/\bunsigned\b/uint64_t/g`.

The `\b` is the interesting bit.  In regularl expressions, it matches word boundaries.

Comment: Or for all files : 
`find . -name "*.cpp" -exec sed -i "s/\bunsigned\b/uint64_t/g" '{}' \;`

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help. But I am afraid after replacing ...I ended up getting the error as mentioned in my edited question. Is there some other way out

Comment: @AliceEverett this is just a hint, don't you see your `unsigned` is still there. You know why you're getting errors, compiler tells you all.